# Link dylib in macOs QT project

Tags: c++, macos, qt, g++, dylib

I tried a simple dylib in macOS and compiled with g++. I made a small sample to test the lib, it works perfect.
Now I made a simple QT app, linked the lib and added the header to the mainwindow.cpp and I always got a fail message Reason: image not found

I read the web and also some other cases here but all is basing on paths.I think it is is not a path problem. Because I made all changes I read in all the cases and also copied the lib in all needed folders, like project folder, build folder. Nothing helps.

I think that QT cannot work with the library and I missed some needed code, like for initialize or export. So that the problem is more inside the dylib and not in QT or Paths values.

Maybe someone can help me here out?

I have tried:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mylib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mylib
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/mylib/ -lmylib
```

I tried to copy the lib to the build folder and also to the executable folder.

Also edited:

```
/⁨Users⁩/⁨ingoforster⁩/Documents⁩/Development⁩/Playground⁩/TestGround⁩/mylib:/Users/ingoforster/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib 
in Project settings DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH 
Set also to DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
```

Cpp

```
#include "mylib.hpp"

char *mMessage(void) {
    return "Ein sonniger Tag";
}
```

header

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char *mMessage(void);
```

compiled with
g++ -std=c++0x --verbose -dynamiclib -o libmylib.dylib mylib.cpp

Sample

```
#include "mylib.hpp"

int main(void){

    char* Ingo = mMessage();
    std::cout << mMessage();

}
```

compiled with
g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -L./ -lmylib

Actual result is that the sample runs perfect. 
But in QT I got:

dyld: Library not loaded: libmylib.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ingoforster/Documents/Development/Playground/build-TestGround-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_clang_64bit-Debug/TestGround.app/Contents/MacOS/TestGround
  Reason: image not found
10:09:05: The program has unexpectedly finished.
10:09:05: The process was ended forcefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/Users/ingoforster/Documents/Development/Playground/build-TestGround-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_clang_64bit-Debug/TestGround.app/Contents/MacOS/TestGround` appears to be compile-linked to your library code but perhaps has not been formally installed to the executable. `macdeployqt` usually deals with this issue. 
You may also do this manually with `otool` and `install_name_tool`:

`otool -L /path/to/executable`

This will list the installed paths to the dylibs in use.  You will see your dylib, that is the "/old/path/to/libmylib.dylib"

`install_name_tool -change /old/path/to/libmylib.dylib /new/path/to/libmylib.dylib /path/to/executable`

Usually, in an `.app`, the dylib is installed to a subdirectory within the `.app` folder.

```
Application.app/
    Contents/
        MacOS/
            executable
        Frameworks/
            libmylib.dylib
```

With `install_name_tool` you can point to the dylib relative to the executable path to make the app portable.
`install_name_tool -change /old/path/to/libmylib.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libmylib.dylib /path/to/executable`

Comment: I see this. Is this the old path?
@rpath/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)

Comment: Yes. And that is okay to keep.  You would then need to add the correct rpath with `install_name_tool -add_rpath ` etc.  you might also have a look at the executable's load commands with `otool -l /path/to/executable` to see what rpaths are already specified,

Comment: But what is /path/to/executable? Is this the path to the TesGround.app?

Comment: In this case it is `/Users/ingoforster/Documents/Development/Playground/build-TestGround-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_clang_64bit-Debug/TestGround.app/Contents/MacOS/TestGround`  normally the .app main program executable will be in `Whatever.app/Contents/MacOS/` (see diagram above). Once it has the right install names, be sure to resolve any subdependencies of the dependent libraries using the same tools.

Comment: None of this solutions works. The app still show "Image not found". I also see not structure to the app (Frameworks)

Comment: Library not loaded/Image not found: use `otool` and `install_name_tool` to fix.

Comment: As I wrote, there is no effect. I use everything that is written here and also that is written in other questions, the QT always start with "No Image Found".

Comment: Can you post the output of `otool -l` and `otool -L` on the binary you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

After some hard investigation and running into the wrong direction with the given answers here I found out, that QTCreator will do all its own:

QTCreator Pro file have to contain:

```
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/mylib/ -lmylib
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mylib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mylib

MediaFiles.files += mylib/libmylib.dylib
MediaFiles.path = Contents/MacOS
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += MediaFiles
```